# How to validate this json file into a correct one?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, subprocess, delimiter

this code generates random json data using faker library.

1.py :

```
import json 
from faker import Faker
import random
from random import randint
import subprocess
fake = Faker('en_US')



for a in range(1):

             abc =  {

            "phone":randint(6666666666,9999999999),
            "name": fake.name(),
            "email": fake.email(),



        }


with open('data.json', 'a+') as outfile:
        json.dump(abc, outfile)
```

2.py

```
   for i in range (20):
       subprocess.call(["python","1.py"])
```

when i call the 2.py . it'll run and store the output using this

```
 `with open('data.json', 'a+') as outfile:
        json.dump(abc, outfile) `
```

so it is storing the json without delimiter, how to store the valid json.

output it is storing:

```
  {"phone":"944078945","name":"elpeto","email":"asdW@gmail.com"}{"phone":"94407894511","name":"deelpeto","email":"zxcv@gmail.com"}
```

outpit i  need:

```
{"phone":"944078945","name":"elpeto","email":"asdW@gmail.com"},{"phone":"94407894511","name":"deelpeto","email":"zxcv@gmail.com"}
```

Comment: Just FYI, your expected output ***is not*** *valid* JSON either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having two scripts, just have functions within one script that do the things you need, maybe?

```py
import json
from faker import Faker
import random

fake = Faker("en_US")


def generate_fake():
    return {
        "phone": randint(6666666666, 9999999999),
        "name": fake.name(),
        "email": fake.email(),
    }


def generate_fakes(n):
    return [generate_fake() for x in range(n)]


def write_fakes(filename, n):
    with open(filename, w) as outfile:
        json.dump(generate_fakes(n), outfile, indent=2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    write_fakes("data.json", 20)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add `","` manually after dump.

```py
with open('data.json', 'a+') as outfile:
        json.dump(abc, outfile)
        outfile.write(",")
```

And just do not do it for the last one.

You have odd way of doing this. Much simpler would be single loop inside `open` as opening file is a heavy operation.

```py
def get_abs():
    return {
            "phone":randint(6666666666,9999999999),
            "name": fake.name(),
            "email": fake.email(),
        }

with open('data.json', 'a+') as outfile:
    for abs in range(random_range - 1):
        output_file.write(json.dumps(get_abs()) + ",")
    output_file.write(json.dumps(get_abs()))
```

Comment: itll create a extra , at the ending right? so i have to remove it using regex ?

Comment: Yes, but if range is not huge, you should just generate fake_emails to list and dump that to file. Simple programming logic is enough. No regex is needed.